# Code to recursively remove adjacent duplicate letters of even count

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Recently I was asked to write code to recursively remove adjacent letters of even count in a live coding test.At that time I couldn't write the code.After that I tried my best to do so.What is wrong with my logic and code?

eg cbbbaaaabbbccc => cbbbbbbccc => cccc => empty string

eg aabbc => bbc => c

eg  abbbccc => abbbccc   - since no letters are repeating in even count

edit - I edited the code acc to Rory's suggestion but still don't understand that why after the string becomes empty it goes to the recursive call and not just go out of the loop

```
str = "cbbbaaaabbbccc"   


def remUtil(str):
i = 0
ind = 0
while i < (len(str)-1):
    j = 0
    if str[i] == str[i + 1]:
        j = i
        ind = i
        count = 0
        while j < len(str)-1 and str[j] == str[j + 1]:
            count = count + 1
            j = j + 1
            i = i + 1
        # if the no. of comparisons are odd then even letters compared
        if count % 2 != 0:
            str = str[:(ind)] + str[(ind + count) + 1:]
            #print(str)
            remUtil(str)


    else:
        i = i + 1
```

Comment: @RoryDaulton , I put the examples.

Comment: Your examples slightly improved the problem specification but did not answer all my concerns. What about the situations where a letter is in multiple places (such as `'aaba'` and `'aaaba'`)? Also, is recursion actually required? It seems to me that iteration with a `while` loop would be more clear and efficient.

Comment: @RoryDaulton That's why I wrote adjacent letters

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes, count of adjacent repeated letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some inefficiencies in your code, but the errors you are getting come from not being careful enough in preventing your indices from running beyond the end of your string.

First, your line `while i < (len(str)):` prevents `i` from being too large. However, two lines later you use `i + 1` which can be too large. Therefore you do not just want to keep `i` inside your string, you also want to prevent it from pointing to the end of the string. You can do this by changing the line to

```
while i < len(str) - 1:
```

Second, your loop on `j` does not prevent `j` or `j + 1` from running beyond the end of the string. Replace your line `while str[j] == str[j + 1]:` with

```
while j < len(str) - 1 and str[j] == str[j + 1]:
```

I also removed a bad indentation in your second line, which is critical in Python. With those changes, your code then seems to work. You could improve the code in other ways, but the code gets the correct results in the examples I threw at it.

---

Your code does not return anything, it just prints the intermediate and final values of the string. If you want to return the final value and not print in the string (the usual goals of a routine like this), remove the `print` line, store the changed value of `str` back into `str`, and place the line `return str` at the end of the function. The following is your code with all these modifications. I would not quite do it this way, but this code does minimal changes to your code but gives the proper results.

```
#str = "cbbbaaaabbbccc"   
str = "aabbd"     

def remUtil(str):
    i = 0
    ind = 0
    while i < len(str) - 1:
        j = 0
        if str[i] == str[i + 1]:
            j = i
            ind = i
            count = 0
            while j < len(str) - 1 and str[j] == str[j + 1]:
                count = count + 1
                j = j + 1
                i = i + 1
        # if the no. of comparisons are odd then even letters compared
            if count % 2 != 0:
                str = str[:(ind)] + str[(ind + count) + 1:]
                str = remUtil(str)
        else:
            i = i + 1
    return str

print(remUtil(str))
```

Comment: Did you get an empty string for the input "cbbbaaaabbbccc"? I am getting cccc

Comment: @Pooja: Yes, I get an empty string. The way your code prints makes it difficult to tell when the result is an empty string, but look for a final blank line in the output. If there is a final blank line, the final result is an empty string. Note that your code only prints the intermediate and final results but does not return any value to the calling routine. I assume that is what you want--the code would need to be modified to return the final value.

Comment: You are correct.After applying the corrections you suggested , the errors are gone.While debugging I can see the code working correctly but don't know ehre to put the return statement.

Comment: If you do want to return the final value without printing inside the function, see the last edit to my answer.

Comment: I think it has something to do with how recursive program uses a stack that is why since I was not storing the string after returning it I was getting in answer the last string from where the recursive calling started

Answer (score 2):

A shorter version, avoiding the manipulation of indices:

```
def rm_even_duplicates(s):
    ls = list(s) + [None]
    tmp = [ls[0]]
    out = []
    for c in ls[1:]:
        if c != tmp[0]:
            if len(tmp) % 2 == 1:
                out.extend(tmp)
            tmp = []
        tmp.append(c)
    # The recursive part, if you want to do it that way;
    # that could as well have been a while loop
    if len(out) == len(s):
        return ''.join(out)
    else:
        return rm_even_duplicates(out)
```

Some examples and your test cases:

```
print(rm_even_duplicates('aaabbcdddd'))
# aaac
print(rm_even_duplicates('aaabbccaaadda'))
# aaaaaaa

assert rm_even_duplicates('cbbbaaaabbbccc') == ''
assert rm_even_duplicates('aabbc') == 'c'
assert rm_even_duplicates('abbbccc') == 'abbbccc'
```

Answer (score 1):

I try to never miss an opportunity to throw an itertools `groupby` at a sequence counting problem:

```
from itertools import groupby

def remUtil(str_or_list):
    characters = []
    length = 0

    for _, group in groupby(str_or_list):
        sub_characters = list(group)
        sub_length = len(sub_characters)

        if sub_length % 2:
            characters.extend(sub_characters)
            length += sub_length

    if length == len(str_or_list):
        return str_or_list if isinstance(str_or_list, str) else ''.join(str_or_list)

    return remUtil(characters)


# Borrowing @ThierryLathuille's test cases (+1)

print(remUtil('aaabbcdddd'))
print(remUtil('aaabbccaaadda'))

assert remUtil('cbbbaaaabbbccc') == ''
assert remUtil('aabbc') == 'c'
assert remUtil('abbbccc') == 'abbbccc'
```